# Paypal Chained Payment - Shipping Details

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained

Is there anyway to prepopulate shipping details for Paypal or at least pull shipping info for a users paypal account so when the seller gets the payment they can access that info instead of having to email the buyer to get their shipping details?

Based on other suggestions I saw online, I tried adding this line, but the payment still comes through as SERVICES instead of GOODS.

```
    primaryReceiver.paymentType = "GOODS";
```

Thanks for the input, I'm trying to streamline my checkout process so I only have to collect the buyer email instead of all their shipping details.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [SetPaymentOptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/) and you can include a shipping address.

You'll call it right after the Pay call but before you redirect to PayPal so you can add additional details to the payment.

Comment: Thanks so the code would look something like this? http://pastebin.com/nQNcBAEs

How about if I didn't want to pass that info over and just wanted to set the transaction to GOODS so Paypal uses the shipping info from the buyer?